# Weird lines when using psplot and pspicture*

Tags: pstricks, pspicture

I've run into a problem when using `psplot` in combination with `pspicture*`.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psplot{-2}{2}{x 2 exp}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf, this generates a nice-looking parabola. When printed on *some* of our printers, the ends of the parabola are connected by a fine line. This line can't be seen when viewing the pdf-file on screen.

I would prefere never to get this kind of line.

Does anyone know what's going on?

(The plots I actually draw are a lot more complicated, so suggestions of other ways of drawing a parabola are not useful.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it. What happens whithout the star version?

```
\documentclass{article
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psplot{-1.4}{1.4}{x 2 exp}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

If this works it is a problem of your printer.

Comment: The point of using pspicture* is that you don't have to work out exactly where to start and where to stop; the graph is cut off outside the picture area. This is used in lots of the examples in the pst-plot manual, so it seemed like the correct way of doing it. Gives the correct result on screen and on about 50% of the printers I have used.

Comment: I know the meaning of the star version ;-) If it happens also without the star version then your printer has a problem with the pdf code.